# Drag & Drop file upload to .PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an image upload/hosting script that I would like to make a bit more functional. The main way I can think at the moment is to incorporate some way of allowing a drag and drop upload.

Are there any simple implementations of this functionality or is it going to require a full re-work of my code?

Any help would be massively appreciated :)

The code is hosted at http://pixxl.us if you want to test the current functionality.

Comment: You should work on your coding subtility ;)

Comment: Drag & Drop is implemented in the browser. You PHP code is only peripherally affected.

Comment: Isn't a file mime type always lowercase? So `image/Png` for example is not necessary.

Comment: @putvande I found that without the specified capitalisations the files weren't hitting the accepted file types as direct matches... this seemed to rectify the issue. I know my code is sloppy - but I'm working on it! :P

Comment: @JackTrigg Use strtolower() before comparing. Then you don't need all those various capitalisations.

Comment: @Lesleh I have done that now - it's enabled me to remove a massive bulk of code - good stuff! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your backend code has nothing to do with drag and drop file uploads, this is handled by the browser (mostly with js libraries). Take a look at [flow.js](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js).